# QGIS context menu always opens on different screen

Tags: qgis, context-menu

I have Macbook and an external screen connected to my Macbook. I have the problem that EVERY single context window I open in QGIS by right-clicking opens on my other screen. No matter if I want to open the attribute table, the properties dialog, use a styles dropdown, etc.

This is very cumbersome for me as a QGIS user but even more for my colleagues in online-sessions when I want to show them something in my QGIS and I share "my screen" (= the external screen). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by making the external screen my main display in Display settings.